# How do i turn multiple of the same object into instances?

Tags: scene, memory-management

I have need to render a scene but have been running into trouble because it would run out of memory. The scene has a lot of leaves (999 to be specific) and they are all identical. How would i turn all of these leaves into a instance of one leaf to save memory and computing power? (All of the leaves are separate objects and already exist in the scene and i do not want them to move)

Comment: Have you tried using a particle system?

Comment: Christopher Bennett, how would i do that without changing where the leaves are?

Comment: Oh, they already exist and are in place? I'm not sure then. You could combine them all into one object with ctrl+j, but i'm not sure how much memory (if any) that would save. Maybe someone else will know.

Answer (score 8):

Select all your leaves (if they have the same material, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> *(Select Linked) > Material*), select one last to make it active, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> *(Make Links) > Object Data*, now all the leaves share the same mesh, they are all instances.

Comment: I should have specified the question more. The leaves are already physical objects and i do not want them to move but share the same meshes and UVs

Comment: @PleaseHelpMe This answer should do what you want with only the mesh been shared among your leaves. Location itself will not change unless they are not same mesh at the first place or there is some complicate structure in your leave object. And you can go *File > Clean Up > Purge all* to delete those original copy of mesh BTW.

Comment: If you change the location in edit mode (which change the mesh). You can first select all and `set origin to center of volume` to make them share the similar mesh. Then do the rest of this answer

Comment: @PleaseHelpMe: as HikariTW says I think my solution is the correct one, your objects won't move, and they will share the same mesh and UV, I it doesn't work please give some details